# My rendered vulkan triangle doesn't match its described vertices

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl, vulkan

It's me again.
I want to update my cg wisdom by implementing a simple Vulkan rendering engine following the many tutorials out there.
So far I've managed to create a triangle using gl_VertexIndeces and now I want to go further and render this primitive using a vertex buffer, but for some reason, my polygon looks like this:
[image: Simple triangle is rendered wrong]

My code is the following.
**Buffer creation and update**

```
VulkanBuffer createVulkanBuffer(VulkanContext* context, uint32_t size) {
    VulkanBuffer output = {};

    VkBufferCreateInfo createInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO };
    createInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT; // i
    createInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    createInfo.size = size;

    vkCreateBuffer(context->device, &createInfo, nullptr, &output.buffer);

    VkBufferMemoryRequirementsInfo2 requirementsInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_INFO_2 };
    requirementsInfo.buffer = output.buffer;

    VkMemoryRequirements2 memoryRequirements = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_2 };
    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements2(context->device, &requirementsInfo, &memoryRequirements);

    VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties2 memoryProperties = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_MEMORY_PROPERTIES_2 };
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties2(context->physicalDevice, &memoryProperties);

    int32_t memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryTypeIndex(&memoryProperties.memoryProperties, memoryRequirements.memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO };
    allocInfo.allocationSize = memoryRequirements.memoryRequirements.size;
    allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = memoryTypeIndex;

    vkAllocateMemory(context->device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &output.deviceMemory);

    VkBindBufferMemoryInfo memoryInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_BUFFER_MEMORY_INFO };
    memoryInfo.buffer = output.buffer;
    memoryInfo.memory = output.deviceMemory;
    memoryInfo.memoryOffset = 0;
    vkBindBufferMemory2(context->device, 1, &memoryInfo);
    
    return output;
}

void updateBuffer(VulkanContext* context, VulkanBuffer* buffer, void* data, uint32_t sizeOfData) {
    void* pData;
    vkMapMemory(context->device, buffer->deviceMemory, 0, sizeOfData, 0, &pData);
    memcpy(pData, data, static_cast<size_t>(sizeOfData));
    vkUnmapMemory(context->device, buffer->deviceMemory);
}
```

**The triangle**
mathfu is a include only math library.

```
std::vector<mathfu::vec3> createTriangle2() {
    std::vector<mathfu::vec3> vertices;
    vertices.resize(3);

    vertices[0] = mathfu::vec3(-1.f, -1.f, 0.f);
    vertices[1] = mathfu::vec3(1.f, -1.f, 0.f);
    vertices[2] = mathfu::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);

    return vertices;
}
```

**The vertex descriptor which is then used for the pipeline creation**

```
VulkanVertexDescriptor createVertexDescriptor(uint32_t stride) {
    VulkanVertexDescriptor descriptor = {};
    descriptor.bindingDescriptors.resize(1);
    descriptor.attributeDescriptors.resize(1);

    descriptor.bindingDescriptors[0].binding = 0;
    descriptor.bindingDescriptors[0].stride = stride;
    descriptor.bindingDescriptors[0].inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX;

    descriptor.attributeDescriptors[0].binding = 0;
    descriptor.attributeDescriptors[0].location = 0;
    descriptor.attributeDescriptors[0].offset = 0;
    descriptor.attributeDescriptors[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;

    return descriptor;
}
```

**Calling the functions described above**

```
 VkViewport viewport = { 0.f, (float)swapchain.height, (float)swapchain.width, -(float)swapchain.height, 0.f, 0.f };

    // vertex sdata
    auto triangle = createTriangle2();
    uint32_t vsize = sizeof(mathfu::vec3);
    uint32_t sizeOfTriangle = vsize * triangle.size();
    VulkanBuffer buffer = createVulkanBuffer(context, sizeOfTriangle);
    updateBuffer(context, &buffer, triangle.data(), sizeOfTriangle);

    VulkanVertexDescriptor descriptor = createVertexDescriptor(vsize);
    VulkanPipeline pipeline = createGraphicsPipeline(context, renderpass, viewport, "../assets/shaders/spv/triangle_vert.spv", "../assets/shaders/spv/triangle_frag.spv", descriptor);
```

**The vertex and fragment shaders**

```
#version 460
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;

vec3 positions[3] = vec3[](
vec3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
vec3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
);

void main() {
gl_Position = vec4(position.xyz * 0.5, 1.0);
color = abs(position.xyz);
//gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexIndex].xyz, 1.0);
}

#version 460
layout(location = 0) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
finalColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Try use `vec3_packed` instead of `vec3`.

Comment: Can you please add how your triangle should look? You screenshot shows a perfectly valid triangle.